# Different prediction: Keras vs. Android + DL4J

Tags: android, keras, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I experience vastly different prediction results when comparing the output of a neural network trained on a GPU in Python(3.5.5) + Keras (version 2.0.8), against the output of the same neural network on Android (API 24) using DL4J (1.0.0-beta2).

It would be very helpful, if someone can share their experience on how to tackle this problem, thank you!

**Importing the model into Android**

The neural network was converted to DL4J format by importing it using:

```
MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(SIMPLE_MLP, false)
```

and storing it using DL4Js *ModelSerializer*.

The model is imported into the Android Application using the DL4J method *restoreMultiLayerNetwork()*

**Model Output**

The neural network is designed to make a prediction on images, of a fixed input shape: Fixed height, width, 3 channels.

**Image preprocessing pipeline in Android:**

The image is loaded as an inputstream from the device and stores it in an INDarray:

```
AndroidNativeImageLoader loader = new AndroidNativeImageLoader(100, 100, 3);

InputStream  inputStream_bitmap = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
INDArray indarray1 = loader.asMatrix(inputStream_bitmap);
```

*AndroidNativeImageLoader()* loads and  re-scales the image.

The INDarray 'indarray1' is rescaled to contain values in range [0,1]:

```
indarray1 = indarray1.divi(255);
```

The INDarray is passed through the network to compute the output:

```
INDArray output = model.output(indarray1);
```

**Image preprocessing pipeline in Python:**

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np

img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(100, 100))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img.astype('float32')/255

output = model.predict(img)
```

**Problem:**

The prediction using Python and Keras differs significantly from the prediction in Android using DL4J. The output is an array of 2 values, each a float in [0,1].
The difference in prediction for a normal .bmp picture taken by a camera is up to 0.99 per element of this output array.

**Tests done so far:**

When using a monochromatic .bmp image(only red or only blue or only green or completely white), the prediction results are almost the same for both environments. They only differ by 10e-3, which can be explained by training on GPU and applying on CPU.

**Conclusion:**
So far I believe, that the image preprocessing on Android is done differently as in Python, as the model output is the same for monochromatic pictures.

Has someone experienced a similar problem? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you file an issue: http://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues with more information and we can take a look at the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DL4J and Android uses BGR instead of RGB. Therefore a color format conversion must be performed.

Kudos goes to @saudet from this Github post:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/6495

NativeImageLoader needs to be loaded with this conversion:

```
loader = new NativeImageLoader(100, 100, 3, new ColorConversionTransform(COLOR_BGR2RGB));
```